# ListView in WPF not filling all available space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I make a ListView in WPF fill all of the available space? I have tried lots and lots of things but none of them work.

Most recently I tried nesting the ListView in a DockPanel and then using a binding on the ListView to grab the DockPanel's ActualHeight. This works well but there are other controls in the container and they need to be accommodated.

I don't really want to have to write OnControlLoaded() and OnControlResized() events and resize the ListView in code. What can I do?

Here is the XAML with the offending SortableListView on line 10.

```
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15 5 5 5">
            <Button x:Name="btnAddCost" Padding="3" ToolTip="Add Cost" Margin="0 0 5 0" Click="btnAddCost_Click"  >
                Add Cost
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnDeleteCost" Padding="3" ToolTip="Delete Cost" Margin="0 0 5 0" Click="btnDeleteCost_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=lvCosts, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource falseWhenNullConverter}}" >
                Delete Cost
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ctrls:SortableListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="lvCosts" Margin="1" SelectionMode="Single" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
ContextMenuOpening="lvCosts_ContextMenuOpening"
DefaultActionSelected="lvCosts_DefaultActionSelected" MouseDoubleClick="lvCosts_MouseDoubleClick"
ItemsSource="{Binding Booking.AdditionalCosts}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Category" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Category.Name}" ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Category">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Supplier" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Supplier}" ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Supplier">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Buy Currency" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BuyCurrency.Name}" ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="BuyCurrency">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Buy Price" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BuyPrice}" ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="BuyPrice">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Sell Currency" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SellCurrency.Name}" ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="SellCurrency">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Sell Price" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SellPrice}" ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="SellPrice">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Margin" Width="180" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Margin}" ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Margin">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="mnuCostOptions" >
                    <MenuItem x:Name="mniAddCost" Header="_Add Cost" Click="mniAddCost_Click" ></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="mniEditCost" Header="View/_Edit Cost" Click="mniEditCost_Click" IsEnabled="False"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="mniDeleteCost" Header="_Delete Cost" Click="mniDeleteCost_Click" IsEnabled="False"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
        </ctrls:SortableListView>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5">
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">Total Buy Price:</TextBlock>
            <rdf:NumericTextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False" MinWidth="50" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <rdf:NumericTextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Booking.AdditionalCostsBuyPriceConvertedTotal" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
Converter="{StaticResource currencyStringConverter}" ConverterParameter="#0.00" Mode="OneWay">
                    </Binding>
                </rdf:NumericTextBox.Text>
            </rdf:NumericTextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">Total Sell Price:</TextBlock>
            <rdf:NumericTextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False" MinWidth="50" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <rdf:NumericTextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Booking.AdditionalCostsSellPriceConvertedTotal" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
Converter="{StaticResource currencyStringConverter}" ConverterParameter="#0.00" Mode="OneWay">
                    </Binding>
                </rdf:NumericTextBox.Text>
            </rdf:NumericTextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">Total Margin:</TextBlock>
            <rdf:NumericTextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False" MinWidth="50" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Binding Path="Booking.AdditionalCostsMarginConvertedTotal" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
Converter="{StaticResource currencyStringConverter}" ConverterParameter="#0.00" Mode="OneWay">
                </Binding>
            </rdf:NumericTextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Booking.SellPriceCurrency.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

Thanks, M

Comment: It depends on what the parent container is. Post some XAML so we can help.

Comment: if you put it in a grid with `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` it will stretch to the limits you imposed on the column it's inside

Comment: Ok, code added above.

Comment: Is the height of the container set? (like the height of the window)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `DockPanel` containing:

1. `StackPanel`
2. a `SortableListView` and
3. another `StackPanel`

1 & 2 are both docked to the Top; 3 is docked to the Bottom. That means you have nothing in the middle, ie. between 2 & 3. Rearrange the order of the elements to place the `SortableListView` third, and remove its `DockPanel.Dock` property so it takes up the remaining space.

In other words, instead of what you have now:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" ... >
    <ctrls:SortableListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" ... >
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ... >
</DockPanel>
```

change it to this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" ... >
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ... >
    <ctrls:SortableListView ... >
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Nope. That didn't do it. The appearance is exactly the same.

Comment: Then it must be due to the element containing the **DockPanel**. I notice in your second **StackPanel** that you are using **Grid** attached properties (Row and Column) yet there is no **Grid** inside the **StackPanel**. I suspect you are using an outer **Grid** that you haven't posted the XAML for in your question. Try posting *all* of the XAML for your window.

Comment: Well there is no grid, those attached properties are hangovers of trying to get this to work!

Comment: Try posting all of your XAML in the question, otherwise I'm not going to be able to solve your problem